# twitterのbot作成について

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm

twitterのbot作成してて詰んでます。

```js
var twitter = require('mtwitter');
var bot = new twitter({
consumer_key:        'hoge',
    consumer_secret:     'hoge',
    access_token_key:    'huga',
    access_token_secret: 'huga',
});
bot.updateStatus("this is test tweet by bot program.",function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

次のエラーが出てしまいます。

```js
TypeError: bot.updateStatus is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ユーザーネーム\twitter_bot\index.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Node.jsはv8.11.4,npmはv5.6.0です。
Node.jsで組もうと思っています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [jaclar/mtwitter: Twitter 1.1 client API for NodeJS](https://github.com/jaclar/mtwitter) に掲載されているサンプルコードを見ますと、`updateStatus()` の前に `verifyCredentials()` が必要に見えます。

Comment: `bot.updateStatus("this is test tweet by bot program.",function(data){
    console.log(data);
});`
の部分を
`bot.verifyCredentials(function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
bot.updateStatus('Test tweet from mtwitter/' + twitter.VERSION,
    function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
);`
に変えてみましたが、
`bot.verifyCredentials is not a function`
と出てしまいます。

Comment: mtwitter のサイトにある様にメソッドチェーンにするとどうなりますか？ `bot.verifyCredentials(...).updateStatus(...)`

Comment: 同じエラー文が出てしまいますね･･･
何か重要なものをDLしてないんでしょうか･･･

Comment: もしかして、インストールしたのは https://github.com/passcod/mtwitter ではないでしょうか？

Comment: そうです。APIの云々でこちらを使うほうがいいとどこかのサイトで拝見したので･･･

Comment: そちらのパッケージの内容を確認すると、updateStatus や verifyCredentials function が存在しません。jaclar/mtwitter の方には存在します。

Comment: mtwitterというのは複数あるのですか･･･しかしjaclar/mtwitterをDLしようとしても前者の方が入ってしまいます。`npm install mtwitter`。どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 今、手元に環境がないので動作確認ができないのですが、`npm install jaclar/mtwitter` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: DLできました。ありがとうございます。
`{ reset: undefined, remaining: undefined, total: undefined }undefined`と出ました。これはもうプログラムの問題なのですかね。